# Does cooking nopales with a copper coin actually neutralize the mucilage, and if so, why?

Tags: food-science, mexican-cuisine, okra

While looking around at different ways of cooking nopales and okra that dealt with the mucilage, I found a [few](https://forkitover.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/ensalada-de-nopalitos-cactus-leaf-salad/) [references](http://patismexicantable.com/print/2012/06/cleaning-cactus-paddles-or-nopales.html) to cooking nopales with a copper coin. Some people seem uncertain whether it's an old wives tale or not, and I haven't found an explanation of why it would work yet, but it seems pretty wide-spread. Does it actually work? And if so, why?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: The mucilage in nopales, or cladodes from Optunia cacti, is caused primarily by the presence polymerized galacturonic acid. This will make water gel quite quickly, and I'm looking for ways to use it to thicken soups, and ways to neutralize it for other recipes, like you. I've found the low moisture high heat method effective so far for producing tasty results with nopales. I'll post back here when I get results! Just giving you the mechanism of gelling as a thing to look into for possible solutions, not directly related to nopal or okra. I'll look at okra too.

Comment: Another thing to mention: nopal mucilage, has been found to chelate some toxic metals, [such as lead and cadmium](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2213343713000201), so it may even be the case that cooking nopal with copper will reduce the bioavilability of copper ions dissolved into solution by cooking (a potentially toxic situation!)

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt, not yet - I'm on a quest for a grocery store that sells nopales at the moment.

Comment: @austinian, yikes, good to know! Might not want to try that right away :p

Comment: I'm suddenly wondering if boiling or steaming *before* spine removal would have the desired effect: non-mucilaginous wet cooking preparations. Dry cooking methods work fine on nopal and okra. I'm also wondering now about sous vide preparation after spine removal... The produce market around the corner from my house sells okra and nopal. I foresee acquiring some on my way home tonight.

Comment: Here's a good article on the topic at hand: [Complex Formation of Copper(II) and Cadmium(II) with Pectin
and Polygalacturonic Acid in Aqueous Solution.](http://www.electrochemsci.org/papers/vol7/7086722.pdf) It has data on how much copper is "sequestered" by pectate (polygalacturonic acid). I'm suspecting that the reason that copper may "neutralize" the mucilaginous texture of boiled nopal is that by chelating the copper ions from solution, the polygalacturonic acid loses its ability to increase the viscosity of water, due to losing its water retention capabilities and becoming more rigid.

Comment: As an aside: I'm going to start looking for literature on polygalacturonic acid forming similar conjugate bonds with Calcium ions, since that would allow us to use Calcium Chloride instead of Copper. Calcium Chloride is GRAS, and also used in canning to "firm up" vegetables. So, using Calcium Chloride in the boil water may lead to similar, safer, results. Also, it sounds like something I'm more likely to put in my mouth. Now I've got to find some Calcium Chloride, here's to hoping they sell it at the grocery store in the canning section!

Comment: That is really cool! This definitely has the makings of being the best of answers. Agreed that I'd much rather use something known to be safe than 'may be toxic, we aren't sure'. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26249/discussion-between-austinian-and-rsid).

Comment: There are more than a few references to bare copper in a boiling situation being potentially very toxic. http://www.gutenberg.org/files/19031/19031-h/19031-h.htm ... that text is ancient, but has a few examples of people ending up dead or sick from copper contaminated food.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across to this website looking for an answer related to sushi rice. Then I started to look around to find out what is all this about, so I found this question about nopal cooking. It happens that I am mexican so I wanted to give some advice about it. I have never seen a person here in Mexico cooking nopal with a copper coin. It seems to me like a  way to do things on those days where people had only copper and "barro" pans and the so to cook. I am not saying there are no people out there who are not using them nowdays, of course, but they might be the least. As I have not done it nor seen it, I can not say if it works.
Maybe I can help by telling you the way I cook them, which is very simple actually. After the nopal has been peeled and washed, I put it directly in a hot pan just like that, let it cook for a moment at medium temperature, then turn it over to allow the other side to cook as well. That is it. No oil, salt, water, and nopal turns just mucilage free. I hope it helps.